Why is SEMRush suddenly registering redirected links (301s) as 404's?
Recently several of our hubspot clients have been seeing spikes of "internal links are broken" and "pages returned 4XX status code" errors on SEMRush. Upon digging in, these are almost purely directing the issues at anchors that point to old url's but have permanent 301's in place. Are there any known bugs or potential culprits that could cause this or is it likely on SEMRush's side?
Disclaimer: I know its harder to debug this without direct details, but this an an issue across multiple sites with very different integrations, themes and assets. Since I've yet to see any posts on it, and it only started happening in the last two weeks, I just wanted to add a space to see if anyone has encountered a similar issue or by some miracle managed to fix it!
Example: Old url - https://www.kaysun.com/are-we-a-fit
New url - https://www.kaysun.com/is-kaysun-a-fit
Attempted:

Checked the sitemap and there are no issues there (old links are removed and 301 redirected-to links are present)
Checked the 301's to ensure the right protocols, full vs relative links, etc
Tried re-scanning after a few days to ensure it wasn't just a temporary issue.

